# change y axis labels in nvd3 scatter-chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter-plot, nvd3.js, axis-labels

I am trying to have my own y axis labels for the bubble chart in nvd3. Currently the labels are [1,2,3,4,5]. I want them to be displayed as [2,4,8,16,32]. I found the following function,

```
chart.yAxis.tickValues(['2','4','8','16','32']);
```

But the labels are not being changed [here](http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html). I am unable to understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These tick values will not have any effect if the `y` values themselves are not within the 2-32 range. Right now that chart only has `y` values up to 2+.

So, if in addition to adding `chart.yAxis.tickValues(['2','4','8','16','32']);` to the Chart Code/Javascript tab as you have in your question, you also make the following change to the code in the Data(JSON) tab...

```
y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 33) // change from y: random()
```

...then you will see the tick values you specified (2-32) show up in the `y` axis.

NOTE: I assume you are looking at the Scatter / Bubble Chart.

Comment: Actually, I am plotting the log scale values but want the axis to have the original values. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Well, that is a change from your original question which I believe I addressed with my response. I also created a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NYJpU/) that illustrates my response. You might want to pose this as another question and use this fiddle as the starting point by adding your data to it. Makes sense?

Comment: @Dinesh it would be easy if you could get the code you've worked on so far to a fiddle, so it easier to help out.

Comment: For log scale, please make another question. The question should be complete from the beginning - in other words, you cant change the question once people started looking - it not fair to them!

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes Please see the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23474319/nvd3-bubble-chart-with-log-scale

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes Can we change the y axis labels to some text we would like?

Comment: @Dinesh Yes, you can...I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NYJpU/1/) with custom labels for the y axis.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes +1 but I am getting "undefined" on the y axis distance when the mouse hovers over a bubble.

Comment: @Dinesh How is this distance being calculated? I just spent some time hovering over bubbles and the axis values are showing correctly for both x and y. Are you calculating this distance yourself and outputting it somewhere?

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes I have not computed any distance not output. I have only incorporated this `.tickFormat(function(d) { return (labels[d]) });`

Comment: @Dinesh And before that statement, have you declared and filled the array like I did in the updated fiddle above?

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes Yes. `nv.addGraph(function() {
  chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
  .margin({left: 100})
  .margin({right: 50})
  .showDistX(true)
  .showDistY(true)
  .color(["rgb(0,200,0)", "rgb(255,95,0)"])
  .transitionDuration(300)
  .xDomain([minYear-1, 2014])
  .yDomain([-2, 6])
  .sizeRange([20, 1000]);
  ;`

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes I figured it out. It works only for those values for which we give the labels. Since I have continuous y values in the plot, I cannot have a label for each value I believe.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes Can we define a continuous function for a new range of y values instead of just at a few ytics?

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes Sorry for too many questions. One last query. Can we hide the "undefined" (y label) from being shown when we hover the mouse over the circles?

Comment: @Dinesh I think you are using a different fiddle with your own data, because I do not see the undefined in the fiddle I updated.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes Ok. I removed the `Math.floor` function and I updated the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/NYJpU/2/. Now you can see undefined.

Comment: @Dinesh I played with it for a while but did not get far. Frankly, I do not think this is the right approach and perhaps not the right tool. NVD3 does not have good documentation and is limited in how much you can customize it. You might want to do this in straight D3. But back to the approach, I think you need to take a step back and re-visit what you are trying to do: you are plotting log scale values but do not want a log scale axis. Does this make sense? Not sure.